# Shared object "libcrypto.so.8" not found

Tags: freebsd

I am trying to run my software and the error message is coming:

Shared object "libcrypto.so.8" not found.

Answer (score 0):

You've, probably, updated base system or port. Recompile your software and relink it with new library.

Answer (score 0):

The program is compiled with OpenSSL from ports, which provides `libcrypto.so.8`.

The base system provides `libcrypto.so.7`.

Install openssl from ports.